# Can't get text user entered from $.ajax-populated textarea

Tags: jquery, textarea

I have a textarea that is added to the DOM and populated after a successful $.ajax call on a php script that queries a database.

A table is generated with the query results and an Edit and Save button are added to each row in the table so the user can change the information.

There are two text-type inputs and a textarea (due to a large amount of data from that column) that the user can change.

The two text inputs work fine (changes are saved to the server). But I'm not able to get the changes that the user made from the textarea.

A table row looks like this:

```
<table id="tblBranchCoverage" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="115px">County</th>
            <th>State</td>
            <th>Zip Codes</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="coverageRow" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <td class="countyCovered" width="115px">
                <label class="branchCountyCovered coverageDisplay" style="display: none;">Barrow</label>
                <input type="text" class="edit editBox editCounty" style="width: 111px;" value="Barrow"><br>
                <input type="submit" class="edit button submitCoverageEdits" style="" value="Save Changes"><br>
                <input type="submit" class="edit button cancelCoverageEdits" style="" value="Cancel">
                <input type="hidden" id="branchCoverageID" value="1">
            </td>
            <td class="stateCovered" width="30px">
                <label class="branchStateCovered coverageDisplay" style="display: none;">GA</label>
                <input type="text" class="edit editBox editState" style="width: 22px;" value="GA" max-length="2">
            </td>
            <td class="zipsCovered">
                <label class="branchZipsCovered coverageDisplay" style="display: none;">30028, 30040, 30041</label>
                <textarea class="edit editBox editZips" style="resize: none; overflow: hidden;" cols="100">30028, 30040, 30041</textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And I'm getting the values of the inputs with this jQuery:

```
$('#tblBranchCoverage').on('click', 'tr input.submitCoverageEdits', function() {

var $tr = $(this).parent().parent(),
    county = $tr.find('input.editCounty').val(),
    state = $tr.find('input.editState').val(),
    zips = $tr.find('textarea.editZips').text();
...
});
```

Checking the contents of the textarea in the console:

```
console.log('zips: ' + zips);
```

Always shows just the text as it was populated, regardless of any changes made by the user. I've also tried .val() and .html() on the textarea, all to no avail.

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working for the textarea only and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: How can the user make changes to the textarea if it has `style="display: none;"`? Is made visible at some stage?

Comment: Something is not real here, You should have some unknown problems in other sides. http://jsfiddle.net/pkgv6/

Comment: @mccannf, I updated my question to include the function that the code is in.

Comment: @Omid, I agree - your jsFiddle works fine, so there must be something else going on. Problem is, finding it. What could be preventing/interrupting getting the user-entered text?

Comment: You're binding event to `input.submitCoverageEdits` while is hidden. How you expect this button to be clicked ?

Comment: @Omid I originally put the code for the row when it is in display mode. I updated my question's code to show the row in edit mode. The input isn't hidden in that case. as you see. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @eventide and where is the `#tblBranchCoverage` ?

Comment: Are you sure you've tried val()?  If you change the javascript on Omid's fiddle from using val() to using text(), you get the exact behavior that you're describing.  val() will get the user input, text() will not.  Try it once more, and make sure your browser is refreshed.

Comment: Switch your comment(s) to an answer - using val() did it. I don't know what the heck was going on, but I'm positive I tried it before. Ah well, at least it works now...